# Is there a Java / Android equivalent to the iOS function "componentsJoinedByString" for an NSArray?

Tags: java, android, iphone, ios, arrays

Is there anything like this in Java?

```
NSString *myString = [myArray componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
```

Here's an example of some output:

```
A, B, C, D
```

If not, what's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`TextUtils.join()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#join%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29):

```
String myArray[] = new String[]{ "A", "B", "C", "D" };
String myString = TextUtils.join(", ", myArray);
```

There is also [a version](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#join%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.Iterable%29) (same syntax) that takes an [`Iterable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Iterable.html) if you need to join something like an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Both good answers but I prefer this as it doesn't add extra dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

One more example Java 8+

```
String[] array = new String[] {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
String joined = String.join(", ", array);
```

Stream

```
Stream.of("A", "B", "C", "D")
      .collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
```